# Loading indicator with SvelteKit and load function

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit app with the following structure:

```
routes
  +layout.ts --> load function is here
  +page.svelte
  page1
    +page.svelte
  page2
    +page.svelte
  page3
    +page.svelte
```

My load function fetches data that I need for the top level route and all three child routes.

Sometimes the load function takes several seconds to finish and in the meantime I would like to display a loading indicator.

My problem is that SvelteKit does not render anything until the load function finishes.

I tried https://svelte.dev/examples/await-blocks and https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#streaming-with-promises but to no success. Streaming with promises is probably not useful because all the data I fetch is essential for my app to work.

I also tried the navigating store (https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores-navigating) but I suppose it does not work because my load function resides in the top level `+layout.ts`.

Comment: SSR works with user-specific data, so not sure what you mean by that. Await blocks will work if you fetch onMount, but not if you leave it in the load function. Recommend using streamed data for your specific problem. If you share some more code, can help with an example.

Comment: Sorry, the SSR part was misleading and I removed it. I will try to create a code example.

Comment: No worries, I'll take a look whenever its ready 